# Added OClint to Obj-c code. But it is not showing warnings

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, oclint, oclint-json-compilation

I tried adding oclint to Xcode referring to this [Doc link](http://oclint-docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/xcode.html) Followed the sane steps as shown in the link.  But I see no warnings. Can somebody help me out here?